# List of Active Calls in Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to get a list of all In-Progress calls for an account in Twilio?

Something like:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/List-In-Progress
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There sure is! When you [list calls from the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list) you can [filter by the `Status`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters). Available statuses are: queued, ringing, in-progress, canceled, completed, failed, busy, or no-answer.

To do this in Node (I'm not sure what language you're using, but we have discussed Node on here before!), you would do:

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.each({ status: 'in-progress' }, call =>
  // do something with the call
  console.log(call.sid);
);
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: That's Perfect!  Thanks Phil.  The app is coming together :-)